# Facebook App - Without SSL

Tags: facebook, security, ssl, canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook App - secure canvas - SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533676/facebook-app-secure-canvas-ssl)

I'm building the facebook App, but looks like I need to buy SSL.
Can someone tell me how to avoid buying?

(I already asked it, but didn't get the exact answer)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you didn't get the answer you were looking for, please edit your original question and make it more clear. Posting duplicate content only creates a lot of noise and clutter on the site. Keep in mind that when you edit your other question, it will get pushed back up to the top of the active list so the community will see it. Good luck!

Comment: thanks, I'm just new this site

Answer (score 8):

Using a host that provides SSL, such as the previously mentioned Heroku, or creating an SSL cert using an open source SSL provider such as [Open SSL](http://www.openssl.org) or [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) are the only ways, that I've seen, to get around buying an SSL cert for Facebook Apps.

However, if you wanted to create a Facebook page tab app, you can get around it by installing the [Static HTML: iframe tabs](https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_plus/)  App in Facebook, and then place your website in an iframe, inside of the content input box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Website</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.example.com" width="520px" height="600px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```